# CentOS 6 SSD TRIM support

Tags: linux, ssd, centos

CentOS 6 is around for quite some time and they provide kernel 2.6.32. I know the vendor versions differ from the [Kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org) ones. Since vanilla kernel 2.6.33 and onwards provide trim support, I wonder if CentOS 6 kernels has this backported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CentOS is made from the opensource [RHEL 6 sources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) from Red Hat. Red Hat has backported the [trim support for SSD](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/newmds-ssdtuning.html) into the RHEL kernel.